# How to copy folder along with items inside to output directory?

Tags: c#, windows, msbuild, output, xcopy

In c# project file, I can use below ItemGroup to copy all items in Folder1 including sub folders into output directory, but not Folder1 itself. I wonder can I copy Folder1 along with all items inside of it into output directory?

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="$(SolutionDir)\ProjectFolder\Folder1\**\*">
      <Link>%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)</Link>
      <Visible>false</Visible>
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're doing. There's not enough context in your question. But if you put the files into a folder in your project, and set each item a `Content` and copy-to-output, then they will be copied using the same folder structure found in the project. You shouldn't have to edit the .csproj directly to get it to work.

Comment: Agreeing with @PeterDuniho - the goal is not evident.  However, you might want to look at [How to: Specify Build Events (C#)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ke5z92ks.aspx) to see if it would let you accomplish what you're trying to do.

Comment: The above script I gave will copy everything under Folder1 to output directory of my project. e.g. under Folder1, I have a folder and a text file: Folder2 and test.txt. After I build the project, I will see Folder2 and test.txt in OutputDirectory. But I want to see Folder1 in OutputDirectory and under Folder1 there are Folder2 and test.txt. Let me know if this isn't clear. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and found a solution by modifying `<Link></Link>` with

```
      <Link>Folder1\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)</Link>
```

if the folder is called `Folder1`.